# Using AltBeacon in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, altbeacon

I hope someone can guide me with this issue. I'm attempting to use AltBeaconOrg, an open-source Android iBeacon wrapper created for Xamarin.

The issue I'm facing is when the listener is implemented in a service as follows, it works fine.

```
    [Service]
[IntentFilter(new [] {"com.testapp.SensorService"})]
public class DroidSensorService : Service, IRangeNotifier, IBeaconConsumer
{
    static readonly string Tag = typeof(DroidSensorService).Name;

    private IBinder binder;

    private Region _region;
    private BeaconManager _beaconManager;

    public DroidSensorService()
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Log.Debug(Tag, "OnCreate called in the Service");
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Service started");
        _beaconManager = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(ApplicationContext);
        _beaconManager.Bind(this);
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        binder = new DroidSensorServiceBinder(this);
        return binder;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Service has been terminated");
    }

    public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
        _beaconManager.SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000);
        _beaconManager.SetRangeNotifier(this);
        _region = new AltBeaconOrg.BoundBeacon.Region("Region", null, null, null);
        _beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(_region);

    }

    public void DidRangeBeaconsInRegion(ICollection<Beacon> beacons, Region region)
    {

    }
}
```

The DidRangeBeacons event is raised when new beacons are found.

If I implement the solution using a class to wrap the beacon code such as:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new [] {"com.testapp.SensorService"})]
public class DroidSensorService : Service, ISensorService
{
    static readonly string Tag = typeof(DroidSensorService).Name;

    private IBinder binder;

    private MyBeaconClass _myBeaconClass;

    public DroidSensorService()
    {
        _myBeaconClass = new MyBeaconClass(this);
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Log.Debug(Tag, "OnCreate called in the Service");
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Service started");

        _myBeaconClass.Start();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        binder = new DroidSensorServiceBinder(this);
        return binder;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Sensor Service has been terminated");
    }
}

public class MyBeaconClass : IRangeNotifier, IBeaconConsumer
{
    private Context _context;
    private Region _region;
    private BeaconManager _beaconManager;

    public MyBeaconClass(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Context ApplicationContext
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.ApplicationContext;
        }
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.Handle;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _beaconManager = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(_context.ApplicationContext);
        _beaconManager.Bind(this);
    }

    public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
        _beaconManager.SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000);
        _beaconManager.SetRangeNotifier(this);
        _region = new AltBeaconOrg.BoundBeacon.Region("Region", null, null, null);
        _beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(_region);

    }

    public void DidRangeBeaconsInRegion(ICollection<Beacon> beacons, Region region)
    {

    }

    public bool BindService(Intent intent, IServiceConnection serviceConnection, [GeneratedEnum] Bind flags)
    {
        return _context.BindService(intent, serviceConnection, flags);
    }

    public void UnbindService(IServiceConnection serviceConnection)
    {
        _context.UnbindService(serviceConnection);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

I get the following error produced:

Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7fefabe700 (key_handle 0x11c1ff5) of Java type 'md53c8887b34fc5ad8a1fb3519f652d3fea/DroidSensorService' as managed type 'Sensors.Droid.Classes.DroidSensorService'.

at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr typename_ptr, IntPtr signature_ptr, IntPtr jobject, IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x00180] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:176 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:ac4a9174-05aa-4926-9a80-8a8455916649 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)

The inner exception is something along the lines of "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context..." (Xamarin Studio cuts it off).

If I move the line instantiating the MyBeaconClass to above the Start() call, the application on the phone crashes with no exception raised in Xamarin Studio.

I appreciate that this code was intended to work in an Activity or a Service class directly, but it would be much neater if I were to be able to achieve this, as I would share this service with other functionality.

Of note: I've tried using the context injected directly and the Android.App.Application.Context directly too.

Thanks very much for reading,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyBeaconClass` has to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object` in order for a JNI Wrapper to be created by `Xamarin.Android` so the Java calls are marshaled to C#. Remember, you are dealing with two VMs that have to be bridged:

```
public class MyBeaconClass : Java.Lang.Object, IRangeNotifier, IBeaconConsumer
{
   ~~~
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer SushiHangover. Sadly your suggestion was not the answer in this case, or at least not solely. In the end I implemented the solution in a service class and called the new service from within the first.

Thanks,

Richard